# What's the main difference between FindClusters and ClusteringComponents?

Tags: cluster-analysis

In many cases, `FindClusters` and `ClusteringComponents` provide similar results. Options for hierarchical and agglomerative clustering are available for both of these functions. So, would you please help me to understand clearly the differences between them?

Just to be clear,my main question concerns about choosing appropriate function for different research questions and anlysis. That is, it's not important if the two functions (or other similar functions) produce different outputs with the same meaning rather I want to know when to use which function and why.

Also, please post any tutorial for cluster analysis in Mathematica if you aware of.

Comment: Did you try http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PartitioningDataIntoClusters.html ?

Comment: @ Rod Lm , yes I did but I couldn't figure out the difference then I posted my question here. I know that there are different options but when results are similar in most the cases and `ClusteringComponents` is faster that the other procedures, wondering what's the advantage of `FindClusters` ?

Comment: Take a look at the difference between `ClusteringComponents[{1, 2, 3, 7, 8}, 2]` and `FindClusters[{1, 2, 3, 7, 8}, 2]` ...

Comment: @ Rod Lm ,just the outputs were different. `ClusteringComponents` gives cluster memberships for each element but `FindClusters` clusters elements into two clusters.The same results!

Comment: "Just the outputs were different" means they are exactly intended to give different types of answer to the same problem...

Comment: It's not clear to me why `FindClusters` doesn't support the k-means and partitioning around medoids methods that are offered by `ClusteringComponents`. In that sense, and apart from the differences in output format, I think this is a fair question.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Have you seen [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/k-means-clustering)?

Comment: @RodLm yes, but it doesn't attempt any explanation of why there are two functions provided for the same operation that each support different methods and produce their output in a different format...

Comment: @OleksandrR. I think this is an interesting question... However, it was asked to point "the differences between them", and, as you've said, the main difference lies in the output format...

Comment: @RodLm well, since (as you point out) the "what" is addressed in the documentation, while the "why" is unlikely to be answerable, I suppose there isn't anything left to say. As such, I'm voting to close as TL.

Comment: I just made my post more clear.  @OleksandrR, thank for the edit!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apart from the output format, the main differences are:

- `FindClusters` can take a custom `DistanceFunction` whereas `ClusteringComponents` can only use those listed in the documentation
- `FindClusters` works with strings and lists of `True`/`False` but `ClusteringComponents` only takes numerical arrays
- `FindClusters` takes a 1D list as input, `ClusteringComponents` can take arrays of any dimension and has a level argument to determine at what level to find clusters

It is also worth noting that with the method options `"Optimize"` and `"Agglomerate"`, `ClusteringComponents` uses `FindClusters` internally. For the `"KMeans"` and `"PAM"` methods there are separate implementations, using `` Image`KMeansClustering `` and `` Image`KMedoidsClustering ``.