# k-means clustering in parallel

Tags: parallelization, cluster-analysis

How can the k-means algorithm for some given distance function be implemented using ParallelMap or other parallel processing program constructs in Mathematica?

Comment: Are you aware that k-means clustering is a built-in method of [ClusteringComponents](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringComponents.html)? It is not unlikely this is already parallelized.

Comment: How could you test if its been parallelized?

Comment: Related: [7441](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7441/731)