# Max iterations in K-means clustering algorithm

Tags: cluster-analysis, machine-learning

I want to use k-means for clustering. I have used the `ClusteringComponents` function but I said how can I control the max-iteration for k-means ?

Comment: You may try `FindClusters[datapairs, Method -> {"Optimize", "Iterations" -> 1}]`

Comment: @belisarius, Is "Optimize" implents the k-means algorithm? It is not noted in the documentation!

Comment: That's what I meant by "try" :D

Comment: You can adapt rm-rf's implementation [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7446/731). Specifically you can change `FixedPoint` to `Nest` and specify the number of iterations.

Comment: @Pickett, Thanks Pickett. I will share my code of Action recognition using DistanceTransform[] to be public