# Clustering using PAM method

Tags: cluster-analysis

Why Clustering using PAM method often attributes one point in the middle of one cluster to another cluster? (for example here [K-means clustering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/k-means-clustering/) )

[image]

I have the similar results with my set of data.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how `ClusteringComponents`'s PAM is implemented, but I strongly suspect that what you observe is an effect of the stopping criteria of the PAM algorithm. E.g. using cluster samples to compute the [Silhouette measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) might produce these kind of results.