# K-medians clustering computation

Tags: data, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

Is there a built-in function for data clustering using k-medians algorithm? I found out about the  `ClusterDissimilarityFunction` of the `FindCLusters` function, but I guess it refers to the distance function (mean for euclidean, median for manhattan etc). So my kmeans using manhattan metric looks like this:

```
FindClusters[Transpose[{height, weight}], 2, 
 Method -> {"KMeans", ClusterDissimilarityFunction -> "Median", 
   "InitialCentroids" -> {{0, 0}, {100, 100}}}]
```

Is it correct? 
How to compute [k-medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering)?

Comment: If it can't be done with the built-in functions, you could take the implementation of k-means from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7446/731) and replace `Mean` with `Median`. That should do it.