# Implement of faster(maybe paralleled) K-Means clustering

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I am writing an algorithm that needs to add noise to the centroid of each iteration on top of KMeans. Therefore, I need to implement a custom KMeans function. I checked out the methods in [Mathematica implement of Lloyd's algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7446/77005), which is helpful. But this code runs slow on my data (my dataset has 6500 2d points). My question is, is it possible to write a faster KMeans method, and even better if it is parallel. Here is my modified KMeans and KMeans++ algorithms. Many thanks!

```
KMeans[list_, k_, opts : OptionsPattern[{DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance,
  "RandomSeed" -> {}}]] := BlockRandom[SeedRandom[OptionValue["RandomSeed"]];
Module[{m = RandomSample[list, k], update, partition, clusters}, 
update[] := m = Mean /@ clusters;
partition[_] := (clusters = GroupBy[list, RandomChoice@Nearest[m, #, (# -> OptionValue[#] &@DistanceFunction)] &][#] & /@m; update[]);
FixedPoint[partition, list];
{clusters, m}]]

KMeansPP[list_, k_, opts : OptionsPattern[{DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance,"RandomSeed" -> {}}]] := BlockRandom[SeedRandom[OptionValue["RandomSeed"]];
Module[{m = RandomSample[list, 1], update, partition, clusters, findCentroid},
findCentroid[] := AppendTo[m, RandomChoice[Min @@@(Table[(SquaredEuclideanDistance[m[[i]], #] & /@ list), {i, 1, Length@m}]\[Transpose]) ->list]];
Do[findCentroid[], k - 1];
update[] := m = Mean /@ clusters;
partition[_] := (clusters = GroupBy[list, RandomChoice@Nearest[m, #, (# ->OptionValue[#] &@DistanceFunction)] &][#] & /@m; update[]);
FixedPoint[partition, list];
{clusters, m}]]
```

Comment: Including data (or code to generate data) on which this algorithm should work would help greatly.

Comment: Thank you, here is the data. http://cs.joensuu.fi/sipu/datasets/unbalance-gt.txt

Comment: Might be good to check this. https://jeremykun.com/2013/02/04/k-means-clustering-and-birth-rates/#comment-29518